# Lesscss - when a number has no units

Tags: javascript, css, less

How do I check if a number has no unit with less? 
There must be a shorter way than:

```
.margin(@i) when (isnumber(@i)) and not (ispixel(@i)) and not (ispercentage(@i)) and not (isem(@i)) and not (isunit(@i,rem)) and not (@i = auto) {
  ...
}
```

I thought `when not (isunit(@i))` would do the trick but this isn't working...

My goal is to use a default unit and work with unit-less functions like ".font-size(10)" as much as possible. The default unit should only be used when the value has no unit, if it has a unit like ".font-size(2em)" the value keeps its unit. When the default unit is "rem" or rem is used as unit, the function must add a pixel value before the rem property (older browsers) and calculate the rem value:

".font-size(5)" should output: (when @default-unit: rem)

```
font-size: 5px;
font-size: 0.5em;
```

I've got this fully working with following functions:

```
.font-size(@i) when (isunit(@i,rem)) {
  font-size: unit(@i*10,px);
  font-size: @i;
}

.font-size(@i) when (ispixel(@i)), (ispercentage(@i)), (isem(@i)), (@i = auto) and not (isunit(@i,rem)) and not (@i = n) {
  font-size: @i;
}

.font-size(@i) when not (ispixel(@i)) and not (ispercentage(@i)) and not (isem(@i)) and not (isunit(@i,rem)) and not (@i = auto) and (@unit = rem) and not (@i = n) {
  font-size: unit(@i,px);
  font-size: unit(@i/10,rem);
}

.font-size(@i) when not (ispixel(@i)) and not (ispercentage(@i)) and not (isem(@i)) and not (isunit(@i,rem)) and not (@i = auto) and not (@unit = rem) and not (@i = n) {
  font-size: unit(@i,px);
}
```

Just seems a bit much for what I want to achieve... could this be shorter?

*Edit*: The answer of Scotts is just what I was looking for, now when I wan't to use 4 values like ".margin(5,10,0,8px)" I call the 4 needed functions: .margin-top(), .margin-right(), ..." This works like it should but the rendered css is quite long... I was wondering what would be the best way to render the css shorthand: "margin: 0.5rem,1rem,0,8px;". Using Scotts function i tried making an example for 2 values:

```
.background-position(@x,@y) {

  .runChecksx() when not (isnumber(@x)) {
    @baseOutputx: @x;
  }
  .runChecksx() when (isnumber(@x)) {
    @tempbaseOutputx: (@x * unit(1, @unit));
    @passedRemx: isunit(@x, 'rem');
    .checkRemx() when not (isunit(@tempbaseOutputx, 'rem')) and not (@passedRemx) {
      @baseOutputx: (@x * unit(1, @unit));
    }
    .checkRemx() when (isunit(@tempbaseOutputx, 'rem')), (@passedRemx) {
      @remBaseAdjx: unit(`(('@{unit}' == 'rem' & @{passedRemx} == true) ? 1 : 0.1)`);
      @baseOutputx: unit((@x * @remBaseAdjx), rem);
    }
    .checkRemx();
  }


  .runChecksy() when not (isnumber(@y)) {
    @baseOutputy: @y;
  }
  .runChecksy() when (isnumber(@y)) {
    @tempbaseOutputy: (@y * unit(1, @unit));
    @passedRemy: isunit(@y, 'rem');
    .checkRemy() when not (isunit(@tempbaseOutputy, 'rem')) and not (@passedRemy) {
      @baseOutputy: (@y * unit(1, @unit));
    }
    .checkRemy() when (isunit(@tempbaseOutputy, 'rem')), (@passedRemy) {
      @remBaseAdjy: unit(`(('@{unit}' == 'rem' & @{passedRemy} == true) ? 1 : 0.1)`);
      @baseOutputy: unit((@y * @remBaseAdjy), rem);
    }
    .checkRemy();
  }


  .runChecksx();
  .runChecksy();


  .checkFallback() when (isunit(@baseOutputx,rem)) and (isunit(@baseOutputy,rem)) {
      background-position: @baseOutputx*10px @baseOutputy*10px;
  }
  .checkFallback() when (isunit(@baseOutputx,rem)) and not (isunit(@baseOutputy,rem)) {
      background-position: @baseOutputx*10px @baseOutputy;
  }
  .checkFallback() when not (isunit(@baseOutputx,rem)) and (isunit(@baseOutputy,rem)) {
      background-position: @baseOutputx @baseOutputy*10px;
  }
  .checkFallback() when not (isunit(@baseOutputx,rem)) and not (isunit(@baseOutputy,rem)) { }

  .checkFallback();

  background-position: @baseOutputx @baseOutputy;
}
```

Using 4 values will make this a verry big less function, any better ways?

Comment: I'm not sure there is an easy answer from native LESS for this, but I do have a question as to what you specifically want to do with this information. Are you attempting to add a unit, but only if the value passed is a number but without its own unit?

Comment: `isunit` is not working the way you want because it requires a second argument that defines a particular unit.

Comment: Edited my post to make clear what i want to achieve...

Answer (score 5):

### Update: Font-Sizing

This may in the future be able to reduce some, but there is definitely a bug with respect to `rem` values that needs worked out in the current (1.4.1) version of LESS. There is still a fair bit of code, but everything stays contained in the initial mixin call.

**LESS (test case with default unit of `rem` set)**

```css
@defaultUnit: rem;

.setFontSize(@i) {
  .runChecks() when not (isnumber(@i)) {
    @baseOutput: @i;
  }
  .runChecks() when (isnumber(@i)) {
    @tempBaseOutput: (@i * unit(1, @defaultUnit));
    @passedRem: isunit(@i, 'rem'); //a bug with rem required this extra step
    .checkRem() when not (isunit(@tempBaseOutput, 'rem')) and not (@passedRem) {
      //keeps passed in non-rem unit or sets to default when non rem
      @baseOutput: (@i * unit(1, @defaultUnit));
    }
    .checkRem() when (isunit(@tempBaseOutput, 'rem')), (@passedRem) {
      //keeps passed in rem unit and value 
      //or sets to a default rem unit but uses passed value for px value 
      @remBaseAdj: unit(`(('@{defaultUnit}' == 'rem' & @{passedRem} == true) ? 1 : 0.1)`);
      @baseOutput: unit((@i * @remBaseAdj), rem);
      font-size: unit(@i, px) * (10 * @remBaseAdj); 
    }
    .checkRem();
  }

  .runChecks();
  font-size: @baseOutput;
}

.test1 {
  .setFontSize(5);
}
.test2 {
  .setFontSize(5rem);
}
.test3 {
  .setFontSize(5px);
}
.test4 {
  .setFontSize(5%);
}
.test5 {
  .setFontSize(5em);
}
.test6 {
  .setFontSize(inherit);
}
```

**CSS Output**

```css
.test1 { /* i.e. unitless 5 with rem default unit */
  font-size: 5px;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
}
.test2 { /* i.e. passed in rem value */
  font-size: 50px;
  font-size: 5rem;
}
.test3 {
  font-size: 5px;
}
.test4 {
  font-size: 5%;
}
.test5 {
  font-size: 5em;
}
.test6 { /* any string */
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe in the future we can use a variable as property like "setSize(margin-left,10);"